# web analytics software which can analyze existing log archives too

Tags: web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, webtrends, log-analysis, urchin

I am looking for a web analytic solution which can also help me to analyze my existing log files. we are moving from sawmill to other solutions.. explored Google Urchin and it has some limitations on analyzing custom existing logs.

Currently exploring webtrends, but i am not sure if it supports custom log analysis

any ideas??

Comment: What do you mean with "custom log analysis"? Why are you moving from sawmill?

Comment: we are moving from sawmill as they found it really slow to query and get reports on a 100M rows log size.. the columns that we capture in the log is not exactly the same format as any standard apache log... there are fields which are very specific to our application. I would like to have an log processor to which can process these fields too apart from standard fields like IP, timestamp, URL etc...

Answer (score 0):

WebTrends will not support custom log formats. Maybe the best way with WebTrends would be to use the Data Collector and/or the API from the Data Collector. Or you put your specific informations within the URL as the Data Collector would do. Here is the link to the API: http://product.webtrends.com/dcapi/sw/index.html

Comment: i have a log archive of around 50 million records... so should i pass them one by one to the data collector API through REST calls .. so its like it has many custom parameters like school_name, teacher_name (many more like this) and stuff apart from the normal parameters like timestamp, ipaddress, url, referrer and all.. so will i be able to create reports on those custom application parameters too???   thanks for your help